# PyAutoGUI in Cron Job

Tags: python-3.x, cron, pyautogui

I'm trying to run a program that automates pulling up a few tabs for me in python(3.6) using Selenium and PyAutoGUI through crontab.

Here's the script I'm trying to run when cron won't run the program:

```
import pyautogui
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

However cron will run the program if I comment out the first line:

```
#import pyautogui
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Here is my CronJob:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:1 ; cd /root/testingDir ; sudo /usr/local/bin/python3 /root/testingDir/test.py
```

PyAutoGUI is installed to /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
and I tried the sys.path.append() trick, but that didn't work either.

I'm confused because it seems like cron specifically won't import pyautogui (I haven't experienced this issue with any other imports. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to send your error to a file like this: ```* * * * * sh script.sh >> results.log 2>&1```

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem as well. Here's how I got around it (with help from the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)). The key is that there are a few missing cron environment variables that are present in the terminal environment variables. Compare the environment variables in each context by:

1. Entering `env` in the terminal
2. Creating a cron job containing `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output` and
       examining the output

I solved this problem by including the following at the top of my cron job that contained the script which called pyautogui:

```
DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/rm/Downloads/bin:/home/rm/.local/bin:/home/rm/bin:/home/rm/Downloads/bin
15 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/<pyscript.py>
```

So looks like the minimal subset of environment variables that must be present is: `DISPLAY`, `XAUTHORITY` and `PATH`. (I got those the variable values by doing `env` in terminal)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all guys! I've spent a 12 hours to solving this issue with pyautogui and crontab, I used a tons chunks of code around of all webresource, eventually:

this option - doesn't work on my machine

```
DISPLAY=:0
XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/rm/Downloads/bin:/home/rm/.local/bin:/home/rm/bin:/home/rm/Downloads/bin
15 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/<pyscript.py>
```

this option - works fine on my machine!:

```
15 * * * * export DISPLAY=:1 && export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority && export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin && /usr/bin/python3 /home/username/Desktop/yourpythonscript.py
```

Good luck to all!